# HERE maps: Can't set ViewBounds from a marker group bounds

Tags: maps, here-api

I'm not able to create a group of markers and to set viewBouns of the map to view all markers from the group. The problem I see is that a default location (somewhere in USA) is set on the map and no markers are visible at all. At the end I want that all markers created from the list of cities in [txt] array. Here's the code:

```
<script>
      // Initialize the platform object:
      var platform = new H.service.Platform({
      'app_id': 'xxxx',
      'app_code': 'xxxx'
      });

      // Obtain the default map types from the platform object
      var maptypes = platform.createDefaultLayers();

      // Instantiate (and display) a map object:
      var map = new H.Map(
        document.getElementById('mapContainer'),
        maptypes.normal.map,
        {
          zoom: 16,
          center: { lng: 51, lat: 12 }
        }
      );

      // TODO: here must be the code which loads the database 
      // with addresses to the txt variable
      var txt = [
          'Blagoevgrad, Bulgaria',
          'Burgas, Bulgaria',
          'Varna, Bulgaria',
          'Veliko Tarnovo, Bulgaria',
          'Vidin, Bulgaria',
          'Vratsa, Bulgaria',
          'Gabrovo, Bulgaria',
          'Dobrich, Bulgaria',
          'Kardzhali, Bulgaria',
          'Kiystendil, Bulgaria',
          'Lovech, Bulgaria',
          'Montana, Bulgaria',
          'Pazardzik, Bulgaria',
          'Pernik, Bulgaria',
          'Pleven, Bulgaria',
          'Plovdiv grad, Bulgaria',
          'Plovdiv oblast, Bulgaria',
          'Razgrad, Bulgaria',
          'Ruse, Bulgaria',
          'Silistra, Bulgaria',
          'Sliven, Bulgaria',
          'Smolian, Bulgaria',
          'Stara Zagora, Bulgaria',
          'Targovishte, Bulgaria',
          'Haskovo, Bulgaria',
          'Shumen, Bulgaria',
          'Yambol, Bulgaria'];

      group = new H.map.Group();

      // Create the default UI:
      var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, maptypes);

      // Enable the event system on the map instance:
      var mapEvents = new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map);

      // Add event listeners:
      map.addEventListener('tap', function(evt) {
        // Log 'tap' and 'mouse' events:
        console.log(evt.type, evt.currentPointer.type); 
      });

      // Instantiate the default behavior, providing the mapEvents object: 
      var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(mapEvents);

      var geocodingParams = [ ];
      var parseList = function prsLst(list) {

      var i;
      for (i=0; i<txt.length; i++) {
        geocodingParams.push({searchText:txt[i]});
      }
      };

      // Define a callback function to process the geocoding response:
      var onResult = function(result) {
        var locations = result.Response.View[0].Result,
          position,
          marker;
        // Add a marker for each location found
        for (i = 0;  i < locations.length; i++) {
        position = {
          lat: locations[i].Location.DisplayPosition.Latitude,
          lng: locations[i].Location.DisplayPosition.Longitude
        };
        marker = new H.map.Marker(position);
        map.addObject(marker);
        //map.setCenter(position);
        group.addObjects([marker]);
        }
        map.setViewBounds(group.getBounds());
      };

      // Get an instance of the geocoding service:
      var geocoder = platform.getGeocodingService();

      // Call the geocode method with the geocoding parameters,
      // the callback and an error callback function (called if a
      // communication error occurs):
      var searchAll = function srchAll() {
        var i=0;
        for (i=0; i<geocodingParams.length; i++)
        geocoder.geocode(geocodingParams[i], onResult, function(e) {
          alert(e);
        });

      };
      parseList();
      searchAll();

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add the group to map and add markers to the group

```
// Initialize the platform object:
var platform = new H.service.Platform({
     'app_id': 'xxxx',
     'app_code': 'xxxx'
});

// Obtain the default map types from the platform object
var maptypes = platform.createDefaultLayers();

// Instantiate (and display) a map object:
var map = new H.Map(
     document.getElementById('mapContainer'),
     maptypes.normal.map,
     {
          zoom: 16,
          center: { lng: 51, lat: 12 }
     }
);

// TODO: here must be the code which loads the database
// with addresses to the txt variable
var txt = [
     'Blagoevgrad, Bulgaria',
     'Burgas, Bulgaria',
     'Varna, Bulgaria',
     'Veliko Tarnovo, Bulgaria',
     'Vidin, Bulgaria',
     'Vratsa, Bulgaria',
     'Gabrovo, Bulgaria',
     'Dobrich, Bulgaria',
     'Kardzhali, Bulgaria',
     'Kiystendil, Bulgaria',
     'Lovech, Bulgaria',
     'Montana, Bulgaria',
     'Pazardzik, Bulgaria',
     'Pernik, Bulgaria',
     'Pleven, Bulgaria',
     'Plovdiv grad, Bulgaria',
     'Plovdiv oblast, Bulgaria',
     'Razgrad, Bulgaria',
     'Ruse, Bulgaria',
     'Silistra, Bulgaria',
     'Sliven, Bulgaria',
     'Smolian, Bulgaria',
     'Stara Zagora, Bulgaria',
     'Targovishte, Bulgaria',
     'Haskovo, Bulgaria',
     'Shumen, Bulgaria',
     'Yambol, Bulgaria'];

group = new H.map.Group();

//DevBab: Add group to the map
map.addObject(group);

// Create the default UI:
var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, maptypes);

// Enable the event system on the map instance:
var mapEvents = new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map);

// Add event listeners:
map.addEventListener('tap', function (evt) {
     // Log 'tap' and 'mouse' events:
     console.log(evt.type, evt.currentPointer.type);
});

// Instantiate the default behavior, providing the mapEvents object:
var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(mapEvents);

var geocodingParams = [];
var parseList = function prsLst(list) {

     var i;
     for (i = 0; i < txt.length; i++) {
          geocodingParams.push({ searchText: txt[i] });
     }
};

// Define a callback function to process the geocoding response:
var onResult = function (result) {
     var locations = result.Response.View[0].Result,
          position,
          marker;
     // Add a marker for each location found
     for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
          position = {
               lat: locations[i].Location.DisplayPosition.Latitude,
               lng: locations[i].Location.DisplayPosition.Longitude
          };
          marker = new H.map.Marker(position);
          // DevBab : don't add markers to the map but to the grop
          // map map.addObject(marker);

          //map.setCenter(position);
          group.addObjects([marker]);
     }
     map.setViewBounds(group.getBounds());
};

// Get an instance of the geocoding service:
var geocoder = platform.getGeocodingService();

// Call the geocode method with the geocoding parameters,
// the callback and an error callback function (called if a
// communication error occurs):
var searchAll = function srchAll() {
     var i = 0;
     for (i = 0; i < geocodingParams.length; i++)
          geocoder.geocode(geocodingParams[i], onResult, function (e) {
               alert(e);
          });

};
parseList();
searchAll();
```